# Hooking into the HTML header container

Tags: plugins, php, themes, hooks, actions

I'm trying to hook into the header.php of wordpress theme(s) more specifically, right before the closing header tag `</header>`. I'd like to do this in a programmatic way so when I switch themes I don't have to remember to go include the method of a custom hook `<?php my_cool_hook(); ?>`

Is there a way to accomplish this? I've tried looking through the available actions but so far I haven't found any that would suite my needs.

Thanks.

Comment: Surely a header tag would be theme specific - so there is no default hook in core.

Comment: True, haven't thought about themes that omitted the header tag entirely.

Comment: I believe the Theme Hook Alliance was, at one point, trying to standardize a whole pile of hooks in various places in themes. [Their GitHub repo](https://github.com/zamoose/themehookalliance) hasn't been updated in a while, though.

Comment: @PatJ that would of been sweet.

Answer (score 1):

Unless a theme provides such a hook there is no way to do this with actions and filters. If a hook is provided then it will be theme specific, no generic WP solution exists.

For a full list of the hooks that a theme should implement, see here:

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/plugin-api-hooks/

At the moment this includes:

- `wp_head()` Goes at the end of the  element of a theme’s header.php template file.
- `wp_body_open()` Goes at the begining of the  element of a theme’s header.php template file.
- `wp_footer()` Goes in footer.php, just before the closing  tag
- `wp_meta()` Typically goes in the Meta section of a Theme’s menu or sidebar.
- `comment_form()` Goes in comments.php directly before the file’s closing tag ()

Note that aside from `wp_head` and `wp_footer`, there is no guarantee that the theme developer knew to add them, or did so correctly, particularly `wp_body_open` and `wp_meta`